# Show progress on Jquery ajax call for sending multiple email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, crm

I'm using ajax to send a single email to all my clients (example before christmas).
Here's the ajax script

```
            $(function () {
              $("#mktg_submit").on("click",function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log($("#mktg").serialize());
                $("#mktg_esito").empty();
                $("#mktg_esito").append("<img src='images/loading.gif' alt=loading title=loading />");
                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'POST',
                    url         : 'json/mktg.php',
                    data        : $("#mktg").serialize(),
                    dataType    : 'json',
                    encode      : true
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $( "#mktg_esito" ).empty();
                    console.log(data);
                    if ((data)["success"]===false) {
                        $( "#mktg_esito" ).append("<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+(data)["errors"]+"</div>");
                    } else {
                        $("#mktg_esito").append("<div class='alert alert-success' id='mktg_mess'><strong>Ben fatto!</strong> Email inviate correttamente.</div>");
                        $.each((data)["email"], function( i, val ) {
                            $( "#mktg_esito" ).append("<p>Email inviata a: <b>"+val+"</b></p>");
                        });
                    }
                    $("#mktg_mess").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
                });
            });
          });
```

Whith this I only see the loading image when the script was launched and I see the result only when all finish. When I send 1.000 email I can't see the progress of the work, can anyone help me to use the best way to see the progress of the sending?

Answer (score 0):

Use the xhr object and attach an event listener to the progress event. [See the reference](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)

Add a div progress to your html

```
<div class="progress"></div>
<style>
    .progress {
        width: 0;
        height: 4px;
        background: black;
        transition: width .3s linear;
    }
</style>
```

Then change your ajax request with something like this :

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                $('.progress').css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
                if (percentComplete === 1) {
                    $('.progress').fadeOut();
                }
            }
        }, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                $('.progress').css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "your-url",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

Comment: Understood, but my question wasn't for an upload progress, I need to have a pregress bar when I'm sending a lot of emails (>500 emails) with my script and I want to see the progress...

Comment: @DellaeMme Did you find the solution for displaying progress bar while sending mass mails.?